# Rest-client Authorization Header unauthorized but working with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, curl, rest-client

I have the following API secured through:

```
  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
    end
  end
```

The following curl works:

```
 curl --data "" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/leadapis -H 'Authorization: Token token="7bbb307792bac1588524003ac641fa55"'
```

Yet in irb>

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/leadapis', '{}', 'authorization' => 'Token token = 7bbb307792bac1588524003ac641fa55')
```

Both curl and rest-client yield the same request.authorization in debugger:

```
(rdb:18) request.authorization
 "Token token = \"7bbb307792bac1588524003ac641fa55\""
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is it that they both yield the same auth when you've written them slightly different in both examples. in curl you write: token="7bbb..." and in RestClient you use a space and no quotes: token = 7bbb...

Why don't you try writing them exactly the same, as in: RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/leadapis', '{}', 'authorization' => 'Token token="7bbb307792bac1588524003ac641fa55"')

Comment: Wow, silly mistake. The extra spaces were it. I didn't think they mattered. Thanks!

Comment: Well yes, to a computer every single little character matters :)